# GWT - refresh button/history/previous UI

Tags: java, gwt

I am just wondering...

When I click refresh button my gwt app comes to its default UI state despite its UI was modified during client-server interactions (callbacks) etc... But sometimes it is really essential thing to "cache" UI if user clicks refresh by mistake or reopened web page which user still logged-in;

So my question is...
Is there a way to restore gwt app UI (its before-refreshed state) in some standard way? Can History tokens help for this kind of issue?

**edit**

Concerning the [history tokens](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html#example) I saw this example :

```
History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
      public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        String historyToken = event.getValue();

        // Parse the history token
        try {
          if (historyToken.substring(0, 4).equals("page")) {
            String tabIndexToken = historyToken.substring(4, 5);
            int tabIndex = Integer.parseInt(tabIndexToken);
            // Select the specified tab panel
            tabPanel.selectTab(tabIndex);
          } else {
            tabPanel.selectTab(0);
          }

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
          tabPanel.selectTab(0);
        }
      }
    });
```

... and I could notice it restores tabIndex from history; so will it help if tab panel won't be init-ed by module load (by default) but something this way:

```
//on button click...
    getSimplePanel().setWidget(new MyTabbedPane());
```

**edit**

To be more clear here is my test code which I am trying to figure out how to restore MainUI I mean its previous UI state as if refresh button wasn't clicked.

the EntryPoint...

```
public class Main implements EntryPoint {
    private SimplePanel simplePanel;
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

        FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
        rootPanel.add(flowPanel, 10, 10);
        flowPanel.setSize("410px", "280px");

        Button setWidgetButton = new Button("Click");
        setWidgetButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                getSimplePanel().setWidget(new MainUI());
            }
        });
        flowPanel.add(setWidgetButton);

        simplePanel = new SimplePanel();
        flowPanel.add(simplePanel);
    }
    protected SimplePanel getSimplePanel() {
        return simplePanel;
    }
}
```

...and composite;

```
public class MainUI extends Composite {
    private VerticalPanel verticalPanel;

    int index;
    public MainUI() {

        FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
        initWidget(flowPanel);

        Button button = new Button("+");
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {             
                getVerticalPanel().add(new Label(""+(++index)+": "+Math.random()));
            }
        });
        flowPanel.add(button);

        DecoratorPanel decoratorPanel = new DecoratorPanel();
        flowPanel.add(decoratorPanel);

        verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        decoratorPanel.setWidget(verticalPanel);

    }

    protected VerticalPanel getVerticalPanel() {
        return verticalPanel;
    }
}
```

...and, as a result, to have "cached" ui state without regenerating it again with extracting strings from history tokens and re-instantiate objects or what so ever...

for example if I have this UI (see image) I am interested to have totally the same one after refresh button is pressed...

[image]

but I am not pretty sure which way should I look for? I haven't seen any gwt snippet in this direction; So I really need your advice what way should I dig in?

Any useful comment is appreciated

Thanks

P.S. GWT 2.3

Comment: I think if you hit "refresh", you unload and load again the application. You can store a few values as parameters, for instance, the ID of the Entity you were editing. If you want to reload the unsaved changes, you might try using a web storage or cookies (I personnaly dislike using cookies)

Comment: No, I mean not to restore some text but how to restore the whole GUI for example not to generate it again on every unload/load events? As usual, browsers cache UI for static web pages so is there a way to achieve the same effect for gwt app web page?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. You mean by caching the javascript, GWT uses perfect caching. If you mean if you are using the application, you open the client form view, if you hit the refresh button, it should load back the client form view, yes, history token is the standard way. http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html. You might want to take a look at this framework https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP if you fancy it.
What I do is to onModuleLoad, check the historyToken, if not empty, reveal that. Revealing can be with done GWTP, or building up theproper state.

Comment: @André I just saw example showing tab panel manipulations involving history http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html#example and I am not sure concerning this snippet please see my question edit...

Comment: well, like Christian said, read the state and build up.
Let's say, you have a client form, when you click on the menu button, what happens? You load up the widget, maybe add another one or two widget on other slots. onModuleLoad will read the historyToken, and will proceed to process as if it was an click at the menu bar, loading up the widgets needed.

Comment: @André I edited my question; watch it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss to store the state into the URLs-Hashtag.

You can use GWTP (as suggested in the comments)

In fact you need to read the Hashtag in your `onModuleLoad` and restore your state.

This may work with [getHash()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html):

```
String state = Window.Location.getHash();
myRestoreStateFromTokenMethod(state);
```

**update**

Here are some snippets to create a push store.

```
List<String> states = [...]

public void onClick(){ states.add("newState");changeHash(states); }


public void changeHash(){
    String hash = states.get(0) + ";"
    for(other states) hash += states.get(i);
    // use a UrlBuilder to set the Hash
}
```

Documentation for [UrlBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/UrlBuilder.html)

Or you can try this: https://github.com/jbarop/gwt-pushstate

Comment: I added more details into my question; watch it please

Comment: The gwt-pushstate seems interesting but I couldn't find any snippet published which show how to use it :( Could you give some useful "how to" tips please?

Comment: I really don't get it does the gwt-pushstate have some "developer guide" or something? I couldn't find any :( If you have some snippets related to gwt-pushstate could you share them please?

Comment: I have never used gwt-pushstate, but there is a example application in the sources. You will need to create a String, which will represent the values in your UI.  The trick is reading the Token in your onModuleLoad(). Then create your view with the state from the token. The String may look like #1.23|5.234234|8.323424|2.533 You will have to split the tolen at the |-char and then to the same stept with your UI, as in the onClick.

Comment: " ...The trick is reading the Token in your onModuleLoad(). Then create your view with the state from the token..." wait a minute you mean I have to regenerate UI with history saved data (Strings etc)? I mean is there some way to emulate "static-like" UI in gwt?

Comment: Emm... in your example you write "states.add("newState");" I just want to ask what means "states" in this case?